# UPDATE error. SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
require_once '../app/config.php';

if (!empty($_POST['update'])) {

 $sql = "UPDATE web_usr SET 
               email = :email, 
               fname = :fname, 
               lname = :lname, 
               web_usr = :web_usr,
               usr_note = :usr_note, 
               avatar = :avatar, 
               usr_skill = :usr_skill 
               WHERE id = :id";


 $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

 $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->bindParam(':fname', $fname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->bindParam(':lname', $lname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->bindParam(':web_usr', $web_usr, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->bindParam(':usr_note', $usr_note, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->bindParam(':avatar', $avatar, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->bindParam(':usr_skill', $usr_skill, PDO::PARAM_STR);

 //Execute the statement and insert the new account.
 $result = $stmt->execute();

 //If the signup process is succesful.
 if($result) {
   echo "Succesed";
 } else {
   echo "gagal";
 }
}
```

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number' in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\otakutangerang_admin\c_action.php:33 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\otakutangerang_admin\c_action.php(33):
> PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\otakutangerang_admin\c_action.php on line 33

Comment: can you highlight your 33 line of code

Comment: You missed ID in list

Answer (score 1):

also you missed it

```
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
```